# understanding and using git rebase

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have read a lot on git rebase for months now. But, I am still not comfortable using it in my day to day development work. Just the way I understand merge in version control tools, is there a way I can understand rebase in git and use it to take advantage of the usefulness it provides?

Comment: http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/rebasing is a good illustration

Comment: I have gone through this. thanks for reminding though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VonC's link is excellent, but it probably only contributes for further reading.

First point to remember is that `rebase` is mostly for your private development branches. Rebase always rewrites history, so it's evil and rude to rebase branches that were already published and merged and are used by other people.

There are two main use cases.

One. Move your development branch to an upstream commit

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Result:

```
  X (feature)                 X (feature)
 /                 =>        /
X-X-X-X (master)      X-X-X-X (master)
```

Two. Clean up the history of your dev branch with an interactive rebase

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i master
```

History:

```
      X (feature)
     /
    X             =>        X (feature)
   /                       /
X-X (master)            X-X (master)
```

`git rebase -i` fires up an editor and gives you a list of commits on you branch. There is a default `pick` operation in front of each. If you keep `pick` nothing will change. You can replace `pick` with other operations.

- `squash` the commit into the previous one, prompt for change description
- `fixup` of previous commit, which automatically retains its original description
- `edit` the contents and description of commit
- Etc etc etc

Best way to learn it is to do it.